# Solving equations where the solution lies in $\{0,1\}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, binary-programming

I have $15$ equations in $80$ unknowns $x_i$. Each unknown is either $0$ or $1$. How do you find a solution to this? If there are multiple solutions, I want to see a couple. If one doesnt exist, how to find a best fit?

The system is of the following form

$$\sum_i a_{ij}x_i=R_j$$

So the $a_{ij}$ and $R_j$ are given strictly positive numbers, where $j$ goes from $1$ to $15$ and $i$ goes from $1$ to $80$.

Comment: Do you really want to solve the equations over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z?$ Only because your unkowns are either 1 or 0 doesn't mean addition shouldn't happen in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Everything is normal except that the unknowns are either 0 or 1.

Comment: I guess one can make this into 1 equation in 65 unkowns by gaussian elimination, then how do you find a best fit?

Comment: @JustMe Since the constraints involve "strictly positive numbers", you're looking for real solutions (that happen to have all unknowns $0$ or $1$). This is **not** the same as solving over the field with two elements.

Comment: Ok I fixed it..

Comment: Ok I dont need the best fit, just a reasonably good one.

Comment: What can you tell us about the values of the coefficients ? Where is the problem originating from ?

Comment: I dont have those details at the moment, might come back with more later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably know, this is called a $0-1$ linear integer programming problem.

Unfortunately, it is NP-hard so you can't do much better than exhaustive trials, and $2^{80}$ is out of reach.

If the $R_j$ aren't so large compared to the $a_{ij}$ (positive), the the number of ones will be bounded and the number of combinations will be lower. Maybe in your case other heuristics apply.

Comment: Are you saying theres no way to obtain a reasonable good fit to the 65 variables equation in reasonable time? Other then guessing randomly?

Comment: Is it smartest to eleiminate 15 variables first?

Comment: @JustMe: yes that's what I am saying. For general coefficients, the exact solution can't obtained in reasonable time.

Comment: @JustMe: $2^{65}$ is still huge.